# A Particular Decomposition of the Simplex

Tags: geometry, simplex

Suppose I have a simplex $S_n$ with unit side-lengths.  Fix a vertex $V$.  Let $A_n$ be the convex polytope whose points are contained within the simplex, where the euclidean distance from each point to $V$ is shorter than the distance to any other vertex.

It should be evident that $(n+1)$ copies of $A_n$ can be arranged to form the simplex $S_n$.  Therefore, we know that the "volume" of $A_n$ is equivalent to the "volume" of $V_n$ scaled by $\frac{1}{n+1}$.  There are still some questions that are bugging me though:

- What is the "surface area" of $A_n$, as a function of $n$ and the "surface area" of $S_n$?  I can do calculations for a given $n$, (by using symmetry and adding the "areas" of each individual "face") but I can't seem to find a general formula.
- Does this polytope have a formal name?

Comment: If it doesn't have a formal name, how about "regular Voronoi-Delaunay hyperkite"? What do you need it for?

Comment: Assuming $S_n$ is the $n$-dimensional simplex (not the simplex with $n$ vertices), it seems to me that $A_2$ will be a sort of "[kite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry))", while $A_3$ seems to be a [trapezohedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezohedron).